# ModelBuilder Part Triangle Weird Behavior on Specific Points

Tags: libgdx

I use libgdx to build Android app. I want to draw 3d triangle. I specified 2 triangles with position:

```
final Triangle triangle3 = new Triangle(
        new Point3(0, 0, 0),
        new Point3(0, -10, 0),
        new Point3(-10, 0, 0),
        Color.BLUE
);

final Triangle triangle4 = new Triangle(
        new Point3(0, 0, 0),
        new Point3(0, -10, 0),
        new Point3(10, 0, 0),
        Color.YELLOW
);
```

Then saved it into array inside my custom class `Shape`:

```
final Shape shape = new Shape(new Triangle[]{
        triangle3,
        triangle4,
});
```

I create ModelInstance:

```
ModelInstance modelInstance() {
    int attr = VertexAttributes.Usage.Position | VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal;
    ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
    modelBuilder.begin();
    for (int i = 0; i < triangles.length; i++) {
        Triangle triangle = triangles[i];
        modelBuilder.part("triangle" + i, GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, attr,
                new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(triangle.color)))
                .triangle(triangle.points[0].vector(), triangle.points[1].vector(), triangle.points[2].vector());
    }
    return new ModelInstance(modelBuilder.end(), 0,0 ,0 );
}
```

And my camera setup:

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera(viewportWidth, viewportHeight);
camera.position.set(0f, 0f, 1000f);
camera.direction.set(0, 0, -1);
camera.near = 1f;
camera.far = 2000f;
```

My problems: Blue triangle not showed, but yellow did showed. BUT, if i swap these two lines below, it showed up. Strange. Any idea why?

```
final Triangle triangle3 = new Triangle(
        new Point3(0, 0, 0),
        new Point3(-10, 0, 0), <-- swap this line..
        new Point3(0, -10, 0), <-- with this line..
        Color.BLUE
);
```

Comment: Where is your camera? Difficult to understand 3d visual questions without screenshots, add some

Comment: its ok. i manage to solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, its normal behaviour. As here said (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Material-and-environment), that default value of IntAttribute.CullFace Material is GL_BACK (only render front faces). My blue triangle can't be seen from front, but after i rotated the camera, i can see them now. The order of triangle points array can affect where the object are facing.

But I want my shape to be seen from any angle, so I finally use `IntAttribute.createCullFace=GL_NONE` material to render, so now the triangle can be seen from any angle.

```
modelBuilder.part("triangle", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, attr,
            new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(color), IntAttribute.createCullFace(GL20.GL_NONE)))
            .triangle(points3[0], points3[1], points3[2]);
```